# How does one go about removing a character in a string using a for loop in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The aim of the code is to go through a string using a for loop and remove certain punctuations specifically (“,”,“.”,“?”,“!”, “;”,“:”) with the statement `if c in (“,”,“.”,“?”,“!”, “;”,“:”)` included. So for I have tried using `stringting.replace(stringting[i],"")` in the 5th line of the code below and then I tried using `stringting.translate()` in line 5 with no luck. Why is it not working?

```
    def removePun(stringting):
      new_string = ""
      for i in range (0,len(stringting)):
        if stringting[i] in (",",".","","?",";",":"):
          new_string = stringting.translate({ord(stringting[i]): None})
      return new_string
```

Comment: whats wrong with just `str.replace`?

Comment: does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string

Comment: Why do you have to use a for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to strip punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string)

Comment: It seems you may have accidentally dropped `"!"`.

Comment: Were you helped by any of the answers provided? If so, please mark one as your accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous approaches to this problem. Try this,

```py
def remove_punctuation(string):
    result = ""
    for punc in ",:;!.?":
        result = result.replace(punc, "")
    return result
```

If you want to use `str.translate()` you need to make a translation table:

```py
t = str.translate("", "", ",:;!.?")
some_word.translate(t)
```

Using `str.translate` is ideal in the case of single-character removals. I go into more details for a duplicate of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69475922/6298712).

Comment: Yep. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't `result` be the variable to be returned not `punc`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of testing if a character is in the tuple and then removing it, it would be simpler to test if it is not in the tuple and then add it to the result - or, better, use a list comprehension which only takes one line of code. So:

```py
punctuation = (",",".","","?",";",":")
def removePun(string):
    return "".join([c for c in string if c not in punctuation])
```

Comment: Note that `str.join` accepts a generator, no need to create an interim `list` in memory. It's also much more efficient to loop through the characters to remove and use `str.replace`, as a naive filtering accumulator must traverse the entire string (consider a large input string, versus a relatively small list of characters to remove).

Comment: @ddejohn true, although, a list will always be created (or else join couldnt be implemented efficiently